# Going one element back BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to check if an element has another element containing a specific attribute (Such as `id=xxxxx`).

This is roughly the structure:

```
> <div id=xxxx....
>> <div id=yyyy.... #
>>> <div id=yyyy.... # All of those have the same attributes
>> <div id=yyyy.... #
>> <div id=yyyy.... #
.....
> </div>
```

I am able to find all yyyy. Is there a way I can traverse back and check if before the element with attribute `id=yyyy` there is an element with `id=xxxx`?

If not, what is another solution I could adapt do do this?

Comment: There's really no need to "traverse back" - what kind of filters are you using?  Add your code to your question

Comment: The filters needed to find yyyy.

Comment: When you say traverse, are you looking for parents or siblings of that element?

Comment: Parents, I want to check if xxxx is present before an element that contains yyyy

Answer (score -2):

findAllPrevious and findPrevious can help you out..Please verify once.